# Copy content of source dir to destination dir having same name but different case

Tags: bash, case-insensitive, cp

I am trying to copy a source dir to destination dir but the problem is that the destination dir has the same name but different case.

For example,

```
cp -rp /mydata/AbC.git/* /target/abC.git
```

To clarify further, i am using dir name as variable in script:

```
cp -rp /mydata/${dir_name}.git/* /target/${dir_name}.git
```

Now if the source dir and target dir are AbC and abC respectively, then the command will fail.

All i am sure is that the spelling is same for both source and destination but the cases are different with no fixed pattern. I checked online but could not find such example. One link suggested using `shopt -s nocaseglob` but that isn't working.

Any help will really be appreciated.

Comment: You mean if the source directory has `FOO` and the target directory has `foo`, you want it to do `cp src/FOO target/foo` instead of creating a new file named `target/FOO`?

Comment: There's nothing built-in that does this, as far as I know. You'll need to write a loop that checks whether there's a file with the same name but different case in the target directory, and then perform the copy.

Comment: No, both src and target dirs contain files. However, i want to copy/overwrite the contents of src dir in target dir

Comment: I am only concerned with the target dir name and not contents inside that dir. As long as i can confirm that src and target dirs have same names (case-insensitive), then i should be able to copy the content of src into target dir

Comment: In that case, what you wrote should work.

Comment: `cp` doesn't care about the names of the directories that you give it as arguments. It will copy everything from `AbC.git` into `abC.git`.

Comment: You're right but the problem is that i don't know about the target dir name. I just know the source dir name and i am using that in the script as variable. If i put the same variable name in target dir, then it will fail because cp will not be able to find that dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-iname` option to `find` to find a name that matches case-insensitively.

```
srcname=AbC.git
dest=$(find /target -maxdepth 1 -iname "$srcname")
cp -rp /mydata/"$srcname"/* "$dest"
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @Barmar! :) I love `find` even more now.